# Adding elements at runtime

Tags: qt, qt4, qml, qt-quick

How can I add an element to any view at runtime?
for example, when some signal is fired, the application should add a rectangle to a specific row.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Component should do the trick.

```
MySignalSource {
    Row {
        id: myRow
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Component {
        id: myRectComp
        Rectangle {
            width: 50
            height: 50
        }
    }

    onSignalFired: {
        var rect = myRectComp.createObject(myRow)
        rect.color = "black"
    }
}
```

Not tested, but it should work like that.

Comment: Thanks blakharaz, I solved my problem using the ListView & ListModel. I think my question wasn't clear.